# Define an operator at the interface level

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, operator-overloading

I have series of classes that I want to support performing mathematical operations with. Let's say it looks like this:

```
public interface IWrapValueBase 
{
    public int aValue { get; set; }
}
public abstract WrapValueBase : IWrapValueBase
{
    public int aValue { get; set; }
    //...
}
public WrapValue : WrapValueBase 
{
    //...
}
```

And I want to create some operators so that I can work with anything that implements this interface. For instance:

```
public static WrapValue operator +(IWrapValueBase first, IWrapValueBase second)
{
    return new WrapValue(} { aValue = first.aValue + second.aValue };
}
```

So I want an operator that will allow any `IWrapValueBases` to be added together using the + operator, and return a new `WrapValue` instance. i.e.:

```
List<IWrapValueBase> myList = new List<IWrapValueBase>();
myList.Add(new WrapValue() { aValue = 1 });
myList.Add(new WrapValue() { aValue = 2 });

WrapValue result = new WrapValue() { aValue = 0 };
foreach(IWrapValueBase val in myList)
    result = result + val;
Assert.Equal(result.aValue, 3);
```

Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to define the operator in the `WrapValueBase` class and cast any `IWrapValueBase` references to a `WrapValueBase`.

My problem with that solution is that it would require each implementer of the `IWrapValueBase` class to have it's own operator definition, when it shouldn't be necessary since we know the interface has the aValue property, so we should always be able to add together two instances that implement the interface, no matter what their type is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Language Specification §20.2 Interface Members

> An interface cannot contain constants, fields, operators, instance
>   constructors, finalizers, or types, nor can an interface contain
>   static members of any kind.

Also you cannot:

- Use an extension method to implement the operator
- Use an implicit cast from the interface to something that implements the operator

It seems like you either not use an operator but a method 'Add' instead or you implement it in the base class. Do you actually have multiple IWrapValueBase implementers?

Comment: I don't actually have multiple interface implementers at the moment, but what I do have is a bunch of places where objects are passed around as IWrapBalueBase type references, because that's the only way I can get covariance in lists. As such, `result = result + val;` only works with an explicit cast of `(WrapValueBase)val`. I suppose it's not such a bad thing to have to do, it just has code smell.